# How can I write negations for this statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Are these negations correct using De Morgan's laws for this statement:

This computer program has a logical error in the first ten lines or it is being run with an incomplete data set.

Negation: This computer program does not have a logical error in the first ten lines and it is not being run with an incomplete data set.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well done! You correctly applied DeMorgan's.  Your answer is a correct negation of the original.

You could, perhaps, negate "incomplete" by changing it to "complete" :

"This computer program does not have a logical error in the first ten lines and it is  being run with an complete data set."