# How to get the negation of logic statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I though getting negation is to get the opposite. Is there an algorithm to do this:

**Find the symbolic form and the negation of the statement**

***If he eats, he will walk home***

My take would be: ***If he does not eat, he will not walk home***

Comment: Do you know the general form of negating an implication? Given the truth table for implication, how can an implication possibly be false?

Comment: My take would have been: "If he does not eat, he will not walk home"

Comment: Do you know the truth table for logical implication? If not, that's the missing ingredient here.

Comment: @user4894, I wonder why my answer above is not correct when this thread is correct.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917449/how-can-i-write-negations-for-this-statement?rq=1

Comment: That statement is "A or B" for which the negation is "not A and not B". Your statement is "If A then B". Do you see the difference? What is there stopping him walking home if he has not eaten?

Comment: @Wither, am not clear - and this has made me to amend my post to include what I posted earlier as part of the question. The negation of "not A and not B" sounds credibly the same as my statement above, that is why I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok let's walk through this. First, the Stackexchange link is a disjunction, also known as an OR statement. Today is Tuesday or my name is Fred. That's true if either today is Tuesday, or my name is Fred, *or both*. (That latter requirement is peculiar to logic. The logical OR is *inclusive*).

Your statement is a logical implication, also known as a material implication.

IF today is Tuesday THEN we'll eat beans.

IF he eats, THEN he will walk home.

Now, a logical implication is true in three cases:

- The IF is true and the THEN is true; or
- The IF is false and the THEN is true; or
- The IF is false and the THEN is false.

The implication is false in one case:

- The IF is true and the THEN is false.

I'm afraid I don't know how to make truth tables in LaTeX but the general idea is this (apologies for the formatting, perhaps someone can help):

P Q    "If P then Q"

T T     -- T

T F     -- F

F T     -- T

F F -- T

If this makes sense so far, then the negation of

"IF he eats THEN he walks home" is

"He eats AND he does not walk home."

Can you see how the second statement falsifies the first? The first statement says that IF he eats, THEN he'll walk home. The second statement says that he DID eat; and he DIDN'T walk home. That falsifies the first statement.

I'm not sure if I said too much or too little. Can you give the context of your question? Are you in logic class? Or is there some other context for this question?

Comment: it is a logic class - via distance learning, Discrete Maths.

This pretty makes sense. It is a wow moment for me, so am absorbing this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @user4894: One last clarification: in the truth table above, there are:
TF --F  ->He eats and does not walk home (which gives the answer)
FF --F  ->He does not eat, he does not walk home - why is this not one of the negation? Is it because it is contrapositive?

Comment: TF -> F is the only circumstance under which the implication is false. P => Q is only false when P & not-Q where '&' is logical AND. So "He eats and does not walk" is the only way "IF he eats THEN he walks" can be false. Are you asking why FF-F is there? Oh darn. Because it's a typo!! It should be FF-T. Good catch. I'll fix it above.